# Poisson log linear Regression: using either R or python

Tags: r, regression, modeling, poisson-regression, log-linear

I was hoping someone can help me with this problem.  I posted a similar question earlier but it's not the same.

**I have the following:**

- A 2x2 matrix of structural connectivity values between brain regions i and j. (Sij)
- I also have a 2x2 matrix containing distance values in mm (gij) between brain regions i and j.

Note: For the gij matrix, all region pairs that are separated by more than 17.4 mm, leads to negligible bias due to distance-related false positive connections so we want to adjust for it.

**I want to:**

- Employ a Poisson regression-based statistical adjustment that yields measures of structural connectivity adjusted for the physical distances between region locations.

Specifically, I want to apply a model that assumes that the structural connectivity Sij connecting regions i and j follows a Poisson distribution with the mean μ(Sij|gij) dependent on the physical distance gij between these regions, i.e. Sij|gij~Poi(μ(Sij|gij)). Therefore, I want to estimate and subsequently adjust for the association between the physical distances and the DTT counts using the effect α1 in the log-linear model log(μ(Sij|gij))=α0+α1gij. Therefore it should be adjusted for (gij) distance.

**The log-linear mean is expressed as:**

log(μ(Sij|gij))=α0+α1gij

Therefore, should I adjust the minimum distance of 17.44 mm by making alpha 0 equal to 17.44?  I'm not sure how to calculate the mean of the log linear regression. Also how would I apply this in r coding? or python in the case of my structural matrix and distance matrix?

Also, 
**Should I do the following in order to apply what I want to do:** 
model=glm(Sij~gij,family=poisson(link=log))

Where along these steps do I adjust for the distance value? and how do I do that?

Comment: 1. It's not clear what you mean by "adjust the minimum distance" in the third-last paragraph. What are you really trying to do there? 2. when you say "calculate the mean of the log linear regression" do you mean to ask how to find the estimate of the conditional expectation $μ(S_{ij}|g_{ij})$ for each $g_{ij}$ value or something else? 3. If the bias is negligible for large distances wouldn't you want a model for the mean that was flat for large distance values and deviated from it for small ones?

Comment: @Glen_b 1. so basically what I meant was that when the distance is less than 17.44m (the two regions are close together) there is a bias in the strength of structural connectivity values so we want to eliminate that bias by adjusting the values that fall below the value of 17.44mm. How we adjust for them I wasn’t sure.  I thought I should do the poisson regression and then from the value I get I correct the distance values (not sure how)

Comment: @Glen_b 2. When I say how to find the mean, I’m basing this off of the Poisson distribution and model expectation which is denoted by E(Y)=µ. The Poisson regression model for counts (with a log link) is: log(µ) = α + βx, so I’m trying to find the log link I guess for each gij value.

Comment: @Glen_b 3. I guess you’re right, I’m just not sure how to do that.. and I thought the poisson model with a log link would be the thing to do in order for this adjustment. The whole point of applying this model I thought was to correct this bias.